# Using systemd-tmpfiles to remove a file pattern by age

Tags: systemd

It seems like systemd tmpfiles.d is replacing tmpwatch in distros using systemd now, therefore how is someone supposed do something like "Delete all files matching /tmp/tmp*.nii if older than 1 day".  I have tried

`r /tmp/tmp*.nii - - - 1d`

The code above deletes these files no matter their age. Deep in the man page is explains the age paramater is not supported by 'r'.  Only by 'd' and 'D' and 'e' which do not work for file patterns. This seems like a common critical function systemd should be able to do if it is replacing tmpwatch

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution I found was to put the involved files in a directory and setup that directory using `e`.

`r` is for remove and not for cleanup, as you mentioned age is ignored for `r`.

`e` supports patterns but not files.